# How to change sharepoint root site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

We currently have an old sharepoint site under the url:
https://companyname.sharepoint.com
This site has the old 2013 sharepoint layout which we are trying to get rid of

We also have a new modern group site with the following url:
https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/newgroupsite
Is it possible to change this one to be the new root site under the url:
https://companyname.sharepoint.com

If it is not possible to do a change like this can i simply delete the old root site and then create a new one with the modern layout? or would deleting the root site delete all other sites and groups under https://companyname.sharepoint.com/[what ever here onwards]

Comment: Please, could you specify with SharePoint version are you working with (2013, 2016, 2019, Online? Let us know if the root site you want to move or change has relevant data you should keep.

Comment: it is Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of changing  the url of the site (that I know of). We have faced that recently.

There are few options you can take. 
1. Delete the root site and create a new one. In that case if you have any subsites under that root site they will be lost

So if you have companyname.sharepoint.com/someSite this will be lost. 
If you have companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite this will be kept as it is a separate site collection.

2.Another option would be to migrate site, so you can use another site to crate your new root and the migrate it with overwrite using migration tool (Like sharegate)